# Unknown options error when trying to run aws s3 copy command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, unix

```
Unknown options: /fls/src_inp_file/test/test_path/test_sub_path/test/abc/std/full/notifier_20221026235214.dat,/fls/src_inp_file/test/test_path/test_sub_path/test/abc/std/full/notifier_20221027153919.dat,/fls/src_inp_file/test/test_path/test_sub_path/test/abc/std/full/notifier_20221028115903.dat,s3://alb-jp-albedl-alb-ext/s3path/s3Main/s3Sub/ALB_ABA/20221028/
```

Getting unknown option error when trying to run the AWS s3 copy command.

aws s3 cp $src $s3_tgt --profile albd_dev_user;

I googled it and understand that there is some space issue. I'm not sure where to fix.

Can anyone guide me on this?

Comment: The variables probably don't contain what you expect. Put an `echo` at the front of the line to see what they expand into, then add the output to your Question. Are you attempting to copy a **single file**, or multiple files?

Comment: I'm attempting to copy multiple files.

Comment: `aws s3 cp` will only copy one file unless using `--recursive`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please put a space (instead of comma) between source and destination(here s3)